# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word reference not found

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Recently, I have been escalated to work in a legacy project. This application is a plugin to Enterprise Architect that extracts the content to a .doc file. The point is, I tried to reference dll from different places, without success.

The error:
`The type or namespace name 'Word' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

The places I have tried reference:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

I am using Vistual Studio 2010 and I have Office 2013 installed in my machine, but also tested in a machine with Office 2010.
Appreciate any help.

Update:

Everywhere in the code the word 'Word' is underlined and the compilation error is above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
namespace EATec.Helpers
{
/// <summary>
/// Classe que manipula documento Word via Interop
/// </summary>
public class MSWordHelper
{
     private static object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAuto;
     private static object wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
    public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document OpenDoc(object fileName)
    {...
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, that sounds weird. Could you please update your question and include the `using` statement from your code, i.e., `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;`? Even better would be a small sample that illustrates which line is causing the compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy apps built against older versions of office may be doing something like (C++):

```
#import <msword9.olb>   rename("ExitWindows","ExitWindowsWRD") rename "FindText","FindTextWRD") rename("ReplaceText","ReplaceTextWRD") rename("RGB","RGBWRD")
```

When I set up a new machine, I have a bat file to re-register the old files:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12 "C:\Source\Office 97 dlls\mso9.dll"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12 "C:\Source\Office 97 dlls\msword9.OLB"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12 "C:\Source\Office 97 dlls\vbe6ext.OLB"
```

This has to be done when it's a newer version of Office installed on the PC.

Please note that regtlibv12 might not be on a windows 8 PC, and will need copying over from your old PC.

(Know this is nearly a year old, but just setting up a new PC at the moment...)